# How do I define a Drupal variable using phpmyadmin?

Tags: 7, database

According to this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1439134), I need to drupal_weight_select_max to 1000 in my Drupal installation. It suggests several methods:

1. Use Drush (Not an option for me as it's on shared hosting)
2. Define it in a module (Beyond my skillset)
3. Define it in settings.php (which seems to break my site. i.e. site doesn't load and I get WSOD)

If this can be done in phpmyadmin, can you please tell me in plain english, step-by-step how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables are stored as serialised PHP strings so adding one to the database manually might just be a pain. You can do it quite easily though, just follow these steps:

1. Download and install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel)
2. Navigate to http://mysite.com/devel/php
3. Put this code in the textfield:

   ```
   variable_set('drupal_weight_select_max', 1000);
   ```
4. Press the 'Execute' button.

If you do want to do it directly in PHPMyAdmin you can get away with a running a single query:

```
INSERT INTO variable (`name`, `value`) VALUES ('drupal_weight_select_max', 'i:1000;')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = 'drupal_weight_select_max', `value` = 'i:1000;';
```

and then flushing your caches.

Answer (score 0):

- find table variable
- check if the variable is not there yet (column name)

  - yes : edit it
  - no : add a new record
- new record :

  - name : drupal_weight_select_max
  - value : i:1000;

Answer (score 0):

This [comment](http://drupal.org/node/1439134#comment-5872228) closer to your, just open phpmyadmin, locate your database on left side, click *SQL* button on the top, and paste SQL code from comment:

```
UPDATE variable SET value = 'i:1000;' WHERE name = 'drupal_weight_select_max';
```

Click *Run*. 

Then you should clear your cache, for this run clearing cache in Drupal in Performance section or do manually:
Locate *Cache* table, click Operations, and click on *Empty the table (TRUNCATE)* link.

But you should be sure that this variable exists in *variable* table. For this, click on *Variable* table, click *Search* button on the top, enter **drupal_weight_select_max** on *Value* for *Name* row and click *Go*.
If table exists, running SQL or updating located row will enough (clear Cache of course), otherwise click Insert and enter values that provided in comment: **drupal_weight_select_max, i:1000;**
For inserting, clearing cache doesn't need.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question, but it is incredibly easy to add a field to the site information page to set a variable, so it can be easily edited. All you need to do is add this hook to a custom module.

```
function HOOK_form_system_site_information_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $form['site_information']['fieldname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Field Title'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('fieldname', ''),
    '#description' => t('Field description'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

}
```

Which would arguably be the correct way of adding a sitewide variable.